How to rotate responsive table in mobile view
I have a blogger website, and there is an HTML table on it (Homepage).
In mobile view, I want to see that table like the image attached below. Please tell me how to do it (final output). I'm not fluent in CSS.

HTML:


<table border="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://hiru.lk/8Ds0Tf" title="" /></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://hiru.lk/8Ds0Tf" title="" /></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://hiru.lk/8Ds0Tf" title="" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Here, using CSS-grids would be a great idea.
Check this example:


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-container>a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container>a>img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* For large screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <a href="" target="_blank">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://hiru.lk/8Ds0Tf" title="" />
  </a>
  <a href="" target="_blank">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://hiru.lk/8Ds0Tf" title="" />
  </a>
  <a href="" target="_blank">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://hiru.lk/8Ds0Tf" title="" />
  </a>
</div>




Thanks for your solution.Can you please explain below?
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

value repeat(3, 1fr) you provided is a shorthand notation that creates 3 columns, each with a width of 1fr.



 table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    /* Small screens */
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
        table {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        tr {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        td {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="" target="_blank">
                    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://hiru.lk/8Ds0Tf" title="" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="" target="_blank">
                    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://hiru.lk/8Ds0Tf" title="" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="" target="_blank">
                    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://hiru.lk/8Ds0Tf" title="" />
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



on smaller screens (max-width: 600px), the table is displayed as a flex container with the direction set to column, which makes the table rows stack vertically. Each table row () is also displayed as a flex container with the direction set to column, which makes the table cells () stack vertically within each row.
